# How does this code generate a unique character 26 times?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner re-learning my python skills. I've been looking through this code and I don't see how it generates a unique random integer 26 times. Can someone explain that to me?

```
import random

alpha  = [" "] * 26

def unique_char():
    notfound = True
    while (notfound):
        possible_pos = random.randint(0,25)
        if alpha[possible_pos] != "*":
            notfound = False
        new_char = alpha[possible_pos]
        alpha[possible_pos] = "*"

    return new_char
def main():

    for i in range(26):
        alpha[i] = chr(i+65) #genderates a-z

    print(alpha)
    for count in range(26):
        good_char = unique_char()
        print(good_char, end="")
    print()

main()
```

Comment: FWIW, `notfound = True/False` alone is giving me an upset stomach. Useless negation is never fun. `found = False`, `while not found` would have been so much more understandable. Then again, this is the least of the problems with this code…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain the code with some comments

But first I will show you a minified version of your program:

```python
import random
import string

alpha = list(string.ascii_uppercase) # generate a list from the alphabet iterator
print(alpha) # print the alphabet
random.shuffle(alpha) # shuffle the alphabet
print(''.join(alpha)) # print the shuffled alphabet
```

and here is the explanation of your program

```python
# This program outputs the chars from A-Z in a random order

import random # import random used to generate random numbers

alpha = [" "] * 26 # multiply the ' ' string 26 times results in a array with 26 spaces [' ', ' ', .....]
# This array will later be set to the alphabet

def unique_char():
    # This function picks char in a fancy way from alpha
    # Tut it will never return a char i has previosly return
    # So all piked chars are only picked ones

    notfound = True # set a boolen to true (this is called flag)
    while (notfound): # while the flag notfount is true repeat that step
        possible_pos = random.randint(0,25) # generate a random number between 0 and 25
        # alpha[possible_pos] will return the a char in the alpha array on the random position from the previos line
        
        if alpha[possible_pos] != "*": # set notfound to false(exit the loop) if the array alpha hasn't a '*' in alpha[possible_pos]
            notfound = False

        new_char = alpha[possible_pos] # set new char to alpha[possible_pos](explaint previosly)
        alpha[possible_pos] = "*" # and set alpha[possible_pos](explaint previosly) to '*'
         # ↑ That means if the random number is again the same number we will exit the loop
    return new_char # return the latest char from alpha

def main():
    for i in range(26):
        alpha[i] = chr(i+65) #genderates a-z
        # chr converts a asci number to a char
    # fill alpha with 'A-Z'

    print(alpha) # print the lphabet

    for count in range(26): # generate 26 unique chars that means every char is generated one time (time inefficiently)
        good_char = unique_char() # generate the random char
        print(good_char, end="") # print the random char without newline -> end=""
    print() # print an empty string

main() # call the main function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this has helped clarify what exactly I'm doing here. Just a quick question: can you further explain your comment here? alpha[possible_pos] = "*" # and set alpha[possible_pos](explaint previosly) to '*'
         # ↑ That means if the random number is again the same number we will exit the loop

Comment: So tell me what you don't exactly understand and I try to explain it to you :)

Comment: ^^^ How does this exit the loop?

Comment: Sorry, i mean how does alpha[possible_pos] = "*" exit the loop? You can't make a space "*" if it already has "*"?

Comment: If you set alpha[possible_pos] to '*' the if check sets notfound to False and the while loop exists because the condition(notfound) is false

Comment: I'm so sorry, one more question - once the spaces are set to "*" what part of the code prevents the same position from being returned more than once?

Comment: So spaces holds the alphabet and if the character 'h' is picked(randomly) 'h' will been replaced with '*' with ```alpha[possible_pos] to '*'```. So the script can't pick 'h' again because it got replaced with ```*```

Comment: No problem :) if my answer helped you it would be nice to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very weird and sub-optimal way to do it, to be quite honest, but let's take a look:

```
alpha  = [" "] * 26
```

this list initially contains 26 spaces, but once we pick a previously unseen random number, the corresponding space is replaced with `*`.

Now, the function `unique_char()` generates random numbers between 0 and 25 until it finds something previously unseen (which may take some time, depending on your luck).

If what you need is to get all the letters in a random order, it's as simple as:

```
import random
import string

letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
random.shuffle(letters)
```

Answer (score 1):

- It populates a list with the characters a-z.
- 26 times it calls `unique_char()`.
- `unique_char` picks a random position in the character list. If the picked position is not "`*`", it returns the character at that point. It sets that position to "`*`".

So, it slowly replaces each character with "`*`", marking it as "already taken". Since it picks the position randomly, overall it returns the characters in a random order.

It's a very bassackwards way of shuffling the list.